# Trying to reference previous value during series variable assignment?

Tags: pine-script

I would like to do the following:

```
thisSeries = 
  someCondition ? 1 
  : someOtherCondition ? -1 
    : thisSeries[1]
```

What I need is to repeat the `previousValue: thisSeries[1]` if neither conditions are met.

I'm getting the error:

`Undeclared identifier 'thisSeries'`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the v2, any variable using recursion must be declared beforehand.

```
thisSeries = 0
thisSeries := someCondition ? 1 : someOtherCondition ? -1 : thisSeries[1]
```

First, the variable is declared as an integer, then we redeclare it using the assignment operator `:=`.